# Angular - Iterate and numerate elements without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angular, counting

Object has 3 properties:

```
public obj;
```

...

```
this.obj = {
  height: 10,
  width: 20,
  weight: 30
};
```

Then I bind buttons with those properties, but I want to numerate buttons and show them only if the property value exist:

```
<button *ngIf="obj.height"> Button <span class="buttonNr">1</span> </button>
<button *ngIf="obj.width"> Button <span class="buttonNr">2</span> </button>
<button *ngIf="obj.weight"> Button <span class="buttonNr">3</span> </button>
```

However, if lets say width is missing, I would get "Button 1" and "Button 3"
and I want them to be numerated normally, no matter which properties exist or not, I want to have Button 1 then 2 then 3...

In case width doesn't exist, I want to have Button 1 for height, and Button 2 for weight.

Now I know how to do it with jQuery, to iterate and populate spans with class buttonNr counting from 1 till the end.
But I'd like to do it Angular way, without jQuery.

---

EDIT:
Sorry, when I saw the first answer, I realized I oversimplified my example: there are various objects.
So imagine there's also

```
public data;
public book;
...
this.data = {
  color: 'blue',
  price: 100
}
this.book = {
  title: 'a',
  author: 'b'
}
```

and then I just keep on adding buttons, but also their display depends.

```
<button *ngIf="data.color"> Button <span class="buttonNr">4</span> </button>
<button *ngIf="data.price"> Button <span class="buttonNr">5</span> </button>
<button *ngIf="book.title"> Button <span class="buttonNr">6</span> </button>
<button *ngIf="book.author"> Button <span class="buttonNr">7</span> </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution could look as follows

```js
<button *ngFor="let key of obj | keyvalue; let i = index">
   Button <span class="buttonNr">1</span>
</button>
```

Let me explain what happens here

1. `*ngFor` is a directive that renders a template for each item in a collection
2. `keyvalue` is a special Pipe that allows iterating through object properties
3. `let i = index` - exporting iteration index into `i` variable

**Update**

According to the answer updated, I've updated my solution to the multiple objects including cumulative counter

Here you can find a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qn8x38?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: sorry my initial question was oversimplified for what I need. Now it's closer to my real app.

Comment: The only downside to this is that the keyvalue pipe will sort the keys, which may not be desired.

Comment: You can provide a sorting function to a keyvalue pipe (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Comment: Otherwise, you should write all your properties manually as in @AlexK solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be explicit about the order of the buttons, you can define a `getButtons()` method on the component:

```
getButtons() {
  return [
    this.data?.color,
    this.data?.price,
    this.book?.title,
    this.book?.author
  ].filter(val => val !== undefined);
}
```

The method takes the ideal order of all the buttons, then filters out the values that don't exist.

Then you just iterate over the result in the template:

```
<button *ngFor="let value of getButtons(); let i = index">
   Button <span class="buttonNr">{{i + 1}}</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This could be the real deal. Thanks